# Good site for python documentation like ruby-doc.org

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation

I love python, but I am disappointed in it's offerings for online documentation. Ruby seems to have many more documentation sites:

- http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/ (I know, this is rails, not just
  Ruby)
- http://apidock.com/ruby/

I am of course aware of the official docs: http://docs.python.org. I am looking for something more robust, with features such as search auto-complete, commenting, etc. Personally, I find the official docs a little bit rigid to navigate and read.

If no such alternative site exists, how would you recommend I go about creating one? Is there some sort of API to query the python docs?

Note that this question is related: [What is good online documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477502/what-is-good-online-documentation)

Comment: I have never had problems simply using google to search the python documentation. Also, I believe it is within the Zen of python to have a single correct way to do a task (such as documentation): "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: For what it's worth, this Python programmer often gets frustrated with ruby documentation.  I really like the Python docs because they serve as a guide rather than just a list of methods.  Perhaps as you grow into a language your brain adjusts to its documentation practices.

Answer (score 2):

This is not another website, but is a different way to access the docs (and may even qualify as an api to the docs if you're being generous). All you need is a python interpreter:

```
import csv
print csv.__doc__
dir(csv)
print csv.reader.__doc__
```

I've found that this is a great way to do a quick check on exactly how to spell a method, or what the order of arguments is, without having to bring up a web-browser.

Or, as pointed out by Steven Rumbalski, there is also the [builtin function `help`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help). This can be used interactively to show more information about a given module. Also, as pointed out by rplnt, many shells have some syntactic sugar to accessing the help/self documentation features of python.

If however, you were actually serious about programmatically creating your own documentation website/system, a decent start could be to crawl through the object hierarchy of a given module, using the `dir` builtin, and compiling the [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) of all the different methods/functions (this is what `__doc__` is accessing).

I'm personally of the opinion, however, that a combination of the interactive help and using `site:docs.python.org` in google is more than sufficient in most cases.

Comment: In [ipython](http://ipython.org/) (maybe in other python shells too) you can type the name of module, class, function, etc... and put `?` after it, press enter and get the information (including the docstring). Using dir on module isn't necessary either as you have tab completion.

Comment: A better way is `help(csv)`.  It will give you the same blurb as `print csv.__doc__`, as well as  all the classes, functions, and data defined in the module.

Comment: Those are good points. I've edited my response to include them. Still, I'm pretty sure the combination of `dir` and `__doc__` is the best way to access these things programmatically (if the op is actually interested in attempting that), which I may not have been clear about initially.

Comment: Ipython also includes tab completion within the current namespace. So you can type csv.<tab> and a popup window will list everything in the csv module.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Thomas Heller's [online help system](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/pyhelp.cgi) for many years as a quick way to access material in the Python Library Reference, Language Reference, and Python/C API manuals.

Since it's CGI based, on Windows one could use something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to make a keyboard macro to access it after selecting some text from within your favorite Python IDE or plain-text editor.